# Adobe illustrator: select all strokes below a certain thickness

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to select all lines in an illustrator document of which the weight is below a certain point size? I'm working on an architecture publication and have to rescale all the plans. And resizing means that some line ticknesses become unprintable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can.

There is a script that does the job.

The script is not mine and I'm just sending the link for that script.

[SelectPathsBySize.jsx](http://kelsocartography.com/blog/?p=1880)

Also, I'm sending an image showing the script in action.

[image]

Comment: T.H.A.N.K. Y.O.U.!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative method that might help you.

You could change your transform settings, so that when you scale, you don't scale the strokes.  That is assuming the lines have strokes, and are not expanded to shapes.  To do that click *Edit > Transform > Scale*, and deselect the option "Scale Strokes and Effects", hit OK. Now when you do a scale transform the strokes will not be scaled.

Examples

The Scale transform setting

[image]

The result of scaling with that option unchecked

[image]

Comment: It's a bit more complex because we have to rescale the drawings. So most of the lines have to become "thinner", but the ones that are to thin should be upscaled to a minimum of 0,12pt. So this resize trick doesn't quite work for this process. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @Wardh82 actually technical drawings should leave the lines as is. But yeah you can also do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and select the one of the lines and try SELECT>SAME>STROKE WEIGHT.  that should select all the instances of the same weight. You can apply that to different variations as well. I have attached a screenshot.[image]

Comment: The OP was asking how to select multiple line weights under a certain weight at the same time.